# SQL Insert with where not exists to prevent primary key issues

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, insert

I have two tables, one with hourly data, the other with a daily sum of that data, I'm having duplicate entry primary key issues so I'm trying to do something like a where not exists BUT I also need to allow the current date (today) to continue adding throughout the day.

Right now I'm trying the following:

```
insert into dailybtuTEST 
SELECT cast(DT as date), SUM(case when `BoilerBTUhr` > 0 then `BoilerBTUhr` else 0 end)/1000000 as BoilerBTU, SUM(case when `InfloorBTUhr` > 0 then `InfloorBTUhr` else 0 end)/1000000 as InfloorBTU, SUM(case when `BufferBTUhr` > 0 then `BufferBTUhr` else 0 end)/1000000 as BufferBTU FROM table_solarhrTEST
where not exists (select 1 from dailybtuTEST where DT = table_solarhrTEST.DT);
```

And I'm getting duplicate entry primary key errors (DT is primary on dailybtuTEST and an arbitrary record number is primary on table_solarhrTEST - I've tried joins, where not exists, etc. and can't for the life of me figure this out even with mining stackoverflow threads.

Please assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert into dailybtuTEST 
SELECT cast(DT as date), SUM(case when `BoilerBTUhr` > 0 then `BoilerBTUhr` else 0 end)/1000000 as BoilerBTU, SUM(case when `InfloorBTUhr` > 0 then `InfloorBTUhr` else 0 end)/1000000 as InfloorBTU, SUM(case when `BufferBTUhr` > 0 then `BufferBTUhr` else 0 end)/1000000 as BufferBTU
FROM table_solarhrTEST s
LEFT JOIN dailybtuTEST d ON d.DT = s.DT
WHERE d.DT IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

The first question I would have would be: Can you redesign the table, or add a new PK other than a `date`?

If the answer is no, then you can look into: `insert on duplicate key update` or `insert ignore` if you really want to ignore the primary key violation and cancel the insert that was attempted.